# Prove that largest root of $Q_k(x)$ is greater than that of $Q_j(x)$ for $k>j$.

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, roots

Consider the recurrence relation:

$P_0=1$

$P_1=x$

$P_n(x)=xP_{n-1}-P_{n-2}$;

1). What is closed form of $P_n$?

2). Let $k,j.\in\{1,2,...,n+1\}$ and $Q_k(x)=xP_{2n+1}-P_{k-1}.P_{2n+1-k}$. Then prove that largest root of $Q_k$ is greater than that of $Q_j$ for $k>j$. Another observation is taking $k,j$ to be even and $k>j$, smallest positive root of $Q_k$ is greater than that of $Q_j$. Without explicitly calculating the roots, is there any way to prove these observations.

Comment: I would recommend using the fact that $P(y)>0>P(z)$ implies there exists a root between $y,z$. Since $P_n$ is monic, it goes to infinity as $x\to\infty$. So, if you show that $Q_k(\alpha)<0$, where $\alpha$ is the biggest root of $Q_j$, you are done.

Comment: Yes, I got this part and deleted my comment. But is it must that $Q_k(\alpha)<0$? I can't find why. Please help

Comment: It just looks like an ugly algebra practice, try to use the reduction. Also, observe that having the result for $k=j+1$ is enough, by induction.

Comment: You are right, it is enough to prove for k=j+1. I don't know how to use reduction here. If you can then please post it as an explicit answer.

Comment: @rational I worked on the problem for a while, found the close form expression for P_n: $$P_n=2^{-n}(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2\sqrt{x^2-4}}(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^n+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}-x}{2\sqrt{x^2-4}}(x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^n)$$, other than that, the question seems hard because I dont know how to find the largest root in terms of k.

Comment: By induction on $n$, we will prove that $\forall k\le (n-1)/2$;
$$P_{k-1}P_{n-k}-P_kP_{n-k-1}=P_{n-2k}$$
Proof:
$$
\begin{align}
P_{k-1}&P_{n-k}&-&&P_k&P_{n-k-1}&=&&P_{n-2k}\\
(P_k+P_{k-2})&P_{n-k}&-&&xP_k&P_{n-k-1}&=&&xP_{n-2k}\\
P_{k-2}&P_{n-k}&-&&P_k&(xP_{n-k-1}-P_{n-k})&=&&xP_{n-2k}\\
P_{k-2}&P_{n-k}&-&&P_k&P_{n-k-2}&=&&xP_{n-2k}\\
(P_{k-2}P_{n-k}-&P_{k-1}P_{n-k-1})&+&&(P_{k-1}P_{n-k-1}&-P_kP_{n-k-2})&=&&xP_{n-2k}\\
P_{n-2k+1}&&+&&&P_{n-2k-1}&=&&xP_{n-2k}
\end{align}
$$
By induction it can also be proved that 
$$P_k=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor} {k-i \choose i}x^{k-2i} $$

Comment: I couldn't go any further

Comment: @Wilf-Fine, have you any idea for 2nd observation in 2nd part?

Comment: Yeah, it can be proven using $${k-i \choose i}+{k-i \choose i+1}={k-i+1 \choose i+1}$$ and  the recursion formula.

Comment: I didn't get how your comment will help in proving 'smallest positive root of Q_k is greater than that of Q_j for even k and j..'

Comment: I'll encourage you to write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The expression for $P_n$ in terms of $n$ is pretty ugly,

$$P_n=xP_{n-1}-P_{n-2}$$

Exact form for $P_n$ can be solved by using characteristic equation:

It comes from guessing $P_n=ar^n$ might be an answer for $P_n$, you can search "recurrence relation" online to see how it works.

$ar^n=x(ar^{n-1})-ar^{n-2}$

$r^2=xr-1$

Here $x$ can be treated as a constant since it wont affect our result,

$$r=\frac{x\pm\sqrt{x^2-4}}2$$

So that means the general form of $P_n$ is:

$$P_n=A(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-4}}2)^n + B(\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-4}}2)^n$$

A and B are constant (with respect to $n$) that  need to satisfy initial conditions.

$$P_0=A+B=1$$
And $$P_1= A\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-4}}2 + B\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-4}}2=x$$

So $$(A+B)\frac x2 +(A-B)\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}2=x$$

$$A-B=\frac{x}{ \sqrt{x^2-4}}$$

So $$A=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}+x}{2\sqrt{x^2-4}}$$

And
$$B=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}-x}{2\sqrt{x^2-4}}$$

Finally,
$$P_n=2^{-n}[\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2\sqrt{x^2-4}}(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^n+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}-x}{2\sqrt{x^2-4}}(x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^n]$$

Answer (score 1):

Claim:
$$
P_n(x)=\frac{\sin((n+1)\arccos(x/2))}{\sin\arccos(x/2)}
$$
This is obviously true for $n=0,1$ and (using $u=\arccos(x/2)$)
$$
P_{n+1}-P_{n-1}=\frac{\sin((n+2)u)-\sin(nu)}{\sin u}=\frac{2\sin((n+1)u)\cos u}{\sin u}=xP_n(x)
$$
so it satisfies the recursion equation.

For $|x|>2$ the formula modifies to
$$
P_n(x)=\frac{\sinh((n+1)\text{Arcosh}(x/2))}{\sinh(\text{Arcosh}(x/2))}
$$
by the usual connection of trigonometric and hyperbolic functions.

---

From this one observes that
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}P_1&P_k\\P_{m+1}&P_{m+k}\end{bmatrix}
=xP_{m+k}-P_{k}P_{m+1}
\\=\frac{\sin(2u)\sin((m+k+1)u)-\sin((k+1)u)\sin((m+2)u)}{\sin^2u}
\\
=\frac{\cos(m+k-1)u-\cos(m+k+3)u-\cos(m-k+1)u+\cos(m+k+3)u}{2\sin^2u}
\\
=\frac{\sin(mu)\sin((k-1)u)}{\sin^2u}=P_{m-1}P_{k-2}
$$
This factorization allows statements on the root set, however the original determinant expression is incompatible with $Q_k$, and the $Q_k$ do not simplify that nicely. However, one gets close with the replacement $(m,k)\to(2n-k,k+1)$ which gives
$$
xP_{2n+1}-P_{k+1}P_{2n-k+1}=P_{2m-k-1}P_{k-1}
$$