# How to find the polynomial corresponding to positive roots of $f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, recurrence-relations, roots

Let $$P_0(x)=1$$

$$P_1(x)=x$$

$$P_n(x)=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^{n+1}-(x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}\sqrt{x^2-4}}; n\ge2$$

and $$f(x)=x P_{2n+1}(x)− P_{2}(x).P_{2n-2}(x)$$

It is given that roots of $f(x)$ are real and symmetric about origin that is $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$ iff $-\alpha$ too is a root. So $f(x)$ has some positive roots.

How to find the polynomial corresponding to positive roots of $f(x)$?

Comment: Could you please show us, what you have tried? Could you tell us something about the background and context of the question? For your $P_n(x)$ have you tried consulting http://oeis.org ? Especially http://oeis.org/A053119 ?

Comment: For $ P_n$, I had a recurrence relation and this is the closed form I obtained for $P_n$. For the context, I was trying to find out some particular eigenvalues of a matrix of order 2n+2 and this is the char. polynomial I got as f(x).

Comment: I general if we think, say we have polynomial $f(x)= (x^2-9)(x^2-4)$ then we know our polynomial will be $(x-2)(x-3)$. But if $f(x)$ is given as $f(x)=x^4-13x^2+36$ and suppose we don't know it roots then how to reach at $x^2-5x+6$. I think its too difficult to derive this.

Comment: Your $f(x)$ seems to depend on $n$, so are you looking for a polynomial corresponding to all positive roots of $f(x)$ for any given natural $n$?

Comment: As far as I understand, your question seems to be generic - given $f(x)$, a real polynomial with all roots real and symmetric about the origin.  Knowing only its coefficients and without finding any roots, you would like to find the coefficients for the polynomial which contains all and only the positive roots of $f(x)$. If this is correct, while I think you could do this in principle using elementary symmetric functions of the coefficients, I suspect finding the roots with a substitution $x^2 \to y$ may be far simpler.

Comment: $f(x)$ doesn't depend on $n$, you are right that I am looking for a polynomial corresponding to all positive roots of f(x) for any given natural $n\ge2$

Comment: Looking at 3rd comment, we see that mere substitution $x^2→y$ doesn't give the required polynomial.

Comment: Can you again check the indices in $f$? Esp. if the first were perhaps $P_{2n-1}$ or the second $P_{2n+2}$?

Comment: @rational  As you have defined above, $f(x)$ **does depend** on $n$.  Perhaps you need to post your original problem and steps taken to reach here.

Comment: @rational I said $x^2 \to y$ helps you find the roots by halving the degree, not the final polynomial directly.

Comment: This is the original problem <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692684/prove-that-largest-root-of-q-kx-is-greater-than-that-of-q-jx-for-kj>

Comment: In order to approach 2nd observation in 2nd part, in <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692684/prove-that-largest-root-of-q-kx-is-greater-than-that-of-q-jx-for-kj> I need only positive roots of f(x). So I asked this question. Pardon for being unclear.

Comment: When $n=3$, $f(x) = x P_7(x) − P_2(x) P_4(x)$.  When $n=4$, $f(x) = x P_9(x)−P_2(x).P_6(x)$.  These two polynomials are not the same.  $f$ depends on $n$.  Your claim that it does not means either you have not written the question you mean, or you do not understand the question you have.

Comment: @ Eric Towers, I am not saying that these polynomials are same. I wish to say that for any $fixed$ n>1, the observations holds i.e. in both the f(x) given in your comments the observation holds good.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $x=2\cosh u$ one rapidly sees that there are no roots $x>2$.

Set $x=2\cos(u)$ for $x\in[-2,2]$, then $\sqrt{x^2-4}=2i\sin x$, $x\pm\sqrt{x^2-4}=e^{\pm i u}$ and
$$
P_n(x)=\frac{\sin((n+1)u)}{\sin u}.
$$

Then
$$
f(x)=\frac{\sin(2u)\sin((2n+2)u)-\sin(3u)\sin((2n-1)u)}{\sin^2(u)}
$$
which can be transformed but not simplified using the cosine theorem $\sin A\sin B=\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)$.

---

Now if one had
$$
f(x)=\begin{vmatrix}P_1(x)&P_2(x)\\P_{2n-2}(x)&P_{2n-1}(x)\end{vmatrix}=xP_{2n-1}(x)-P_2(x)P_{2n-2}(x)
$$
then one would get
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{\sin(2u)\sin((2n)u)-\sin(3u)\sin((2n-1)u)}{\sin^2(u)}
\\&=\frac{\cos((2n-2)u)-\cos((2n+2)u)-\cos((2n-4)u)+\cos((2n+2)u)}{2\sin^2u}
\\&=-\frac{\sin((2n-3)u)}{\sin u}
\end{align}

Comment: can you please look at the question provided in above link. writing f(x) as in this answer might help in proving 2nd observation in 2nd part there.

Comment: Are you sure no roots for $x>2$?  For $n=4$, $Q_4(x)$ seems to have a root near $2.02368\dots$.

Comment: @EricTowers: For some reason I ignored the $f=Q_3$ polynomial as in the question... the no roots refers to $P_n$. As defined in the linked question, the $Q_k$ seem too random to give a nice exercise. Changing the index 2 to 4 ($k-1$ to $k+1$ in the linked question) would similarly give a nice factorization, since then the pairs $(P_1,P_4)$ and $(P_{2n-2},P_{2n+1})$ would again have the same index difference.

Comment: Hmmm...  Then it might be a good idea to edit the answer to mention that everything above the horizontal rule applies to $P_n$, not $f$.